# Packaging a virtualenv

Tags: python, deployment, packaging, virtualenv

I'd like to package a Python virtualenv with [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm), so that I can deploy it to my servers. I want to setup the virtualenv somewhere in my home directory without having to use root permissions, but deploy to e.g. /opt. virtualenv itself seems to have no [destdir](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html) option. I know that there is a relocatable option, but it failed for some packages in the past and I don't trust it to work in all cases. Are there any other options, besides setting up a chroot for packaging or actually setting up the virtualenv in my local /opt directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [this build script](https://github.com/brutasse/graphite-api/blob/master/fpm/build-deb.sh#L21) I've been testing and using [virtualenv-tools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv-tools) for serveral month now to relocate virtual environments and never had any problems. It is easily possible to relocate a virtualenv with e.g. `virtualenv-tools --update-path /opt/my_project/virtualenv` and package it with [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/) afterwards.

Comment: virtualenv-tools seems not to be maintained anymore. If you are using python3 probably you'll need to use virtualenv-tools3

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what [docker](https://www.docker.com/) does.

fpm is good enough for packing the python instance and its third-party libraries. But if you want more customization like environment variables, it can't suit everything.

Comment: docker is absolutely great and you could surely ship a virtualenv with your dockerized application. In fact that would be best practice. But docker is not really a packaging system and it cannot be used in every case. So, this is not really answering my question.